# Excel Parse memo get few sentences into different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a memo field lets say in A1 i need to extract couple sentences into different columns.

There might be 50 sentences and only 1 matches, i need to extract from beg key word to end key word, so everything in-between 2 keywords.

There might only be 1 of the 4 keywords i am looking for in memo field, or 2 in any order, or none at all in memo field.  But if there is keyword there would be start keyword and end key word.

Key Fields  from memo :
PHP , HCP , PCP , PART

IF PHP exists include all characters until HCP, else include until PCP , else include until PART until “ DEA ” 
If PHP doesn’t exists go to HCP, then include all text until PCP, then if Part

Comment: Show us what you have tried, as well as examples of where it has fallen short -- examples of your data and what you want for results.

Comment: =MID(O3,SEARCH("PHP",O3)+3,SEARCH("HCP",O3)-SEARCH("PHP",O3)-4)  what i have now ... kinda works ... but i need to next it how do i nest so it captures and automatically puts each in separate field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the following solution:

```
B1 =IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("PHP",A1)+3,IFERROR(FIND("HCP",A1),IFERROR(FIND("PCP",A1),IFERROR(FIND("PART",A1),0)))-FIND("PHP",A1)-3)),"")
```

Hope this serves your purpose. Cheers,